# Get available hash algorithms in nodejs crypto module

Tags: node.js, openssl, cryptography, cryptojs

I'd like to know if there is a way (API method for example) to know all available hash algorithms (and the exact input name) in NodeJs crypto module.

According to official docs, in createHash function it is said:

https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createhash_algorithm_options

> The algorithm is dependent on the available algorithms supported by
>   the version of OpenSSL on the platform. Examples are 'sha256',
>   'sha512', etc. On recent releases of OpenSSL, openssl list
>   -digest-algorithms (openssl list-message-digest-algorithms for older versions of OpenSSL) will display the available digest algorithms.

So depending the OpenSSL version in the node version I am running, I will have different hash algorithm options? Any way(like API method) to know available hash algorithms in the installed crypto module directly?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "directly"? What sort of interface do you want to see? You can always use try-catch to see if the hash you want is available.

Answer (score 6):

Node's `crypto` has an api for [`getHashes()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_gethashes) according to their documentation.

Sample list

```
let crypto = require('crypto');
let listOfSupportedHashes = crypto.getHashes();
console.log('Total supported hashes : ', listOfSupportedHashes.length);
```

Comment: Also you can get the same result outside of Nodejs context with a *nix command `openssl list -digest-algorithms`.